# While loop data validation

Tags: java

I'm using a while loop to validate data ensuring the user enters only a number between 1 and 6. The loop catches the invalid entry no problem, but then when a correct number is entered it needs to be entered a second time in order to proceed. If I take out `|| menuScan.nextInt() > 6` the loop will work exactly as I need it to but I need to include this line in the loop.

```
while (!menuScan.hasNextInt() || menuScan.nextInt() > 6) {
    menuScan.nextLine();
    System.err.println("Please enter a valid menu option 1 - 6: "); 
}

menuChoice = menuScan.nextInt();
```

Comment: I guess will need more context to answer that one... Could you post the rest of your method? Which method triggers the prompt to enter a new value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the value to your variable in the moment you read it for the first time:

```
while (!menuScan.hasNextInt() || (menuChoice = menuScan.nextInt()) > 6) {
    menuScan.nextLine();
    System.err.println("Please enter a valid menu option 1 - 6: "); 
}
```